# How can I obfuscate a web service?

Tags: web-services, tomcat7, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate a Web Service, but I don't know how to do it. When my Web Service isn't obfuscated, it is running perfectly, fine, but when I obfuscate it, it only give me a 404 Error, and nothing is working anymore.

I'm using Proguard to obfuscate my code. My Web Service is written using Jersey 2.0, and my Servlet container is Tomcat 7.0.

My .pro file is : 
    -injars C:\Users\Quentin\Eclipse\workspace\SemRecSysWS\build\classes
    -outjars C:\Users\Quentin\test
    -libraryjars \lib\rt.jar 
    -libraryjars C:\Users\Quentin\Eclipse\workspace\SemRecSysWS\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\
    -keep public class fr.mypackage.*

I think the problem is coming from the keep options, but I don't know what else I can do.

I also don't know how to obfuscate directly a war file, so I'm just obfuscating the .class files and adding it to the war after.

Comment: Sorry, buy why on earth are you doing this?

Comment: I'm doing this because the web service will be implemanted in a Virtual Machine, and everyone will have access to this VM.

Comment: So this is an IP protection issue?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understood what you mean, but I don't think there is any issue with it. It is intended that the VM is free to use, and so is the Web Service. I just want my code to be obfuscated, so it can't be stolen, that's it.